# How could i extract persian numbers from an image in c#

Tags: c#, ocr, farsi

I want a code that takes the image of a fisherman's check and first accurately detects the location of the fisherman's ID in the image, and then extracts the fisherman's ID, which contains 16 Persian digits, and displays the extracted Persian numbers in the output.

[image]

I write this code but the ocr can't extract all of numbers

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Tesseract;
using Rectangle = System.Drawing.Rectangle;


// Load the image
Bitmap image = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\4020302\\Iron\\f.PNG");

var pix2=Pix.LoadFromFile("C:\\Users\\4020302\\Iron\\f.PNG");
var adadha = "";

using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "fas", EngineMode.Default))
{
    // Create an instance of Page
    using (var page = engine.Process(pix2))
    {
        // Get an iterator over the text elements
        using (var iter = page.GetIterator())
        {
            // Loop through the iterator
            do
            {
                // Get the text of the current element
                var text = iter.GetText(PageIteratorLevel.Word);

                // Check if the text matches the sayad pattern
                var regex = new Regex("^[\u06F0-\u06F90-9]+$");
                var match = regex.Match(text);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    // Get the bounding box of the current element

                    Rect res;
                    var rect = iter.TryGetBoundingBox(PageIteratorLevel.Word, out res);

                    //// Crop the image using the bounding box
                    var subImage = CropImage(image, res);

                    //// Save or display the sub-image
                    subImage.Save("sayad_id.png");
                    Console.WriteLine("The sayad id in the image is: " + text);
                    Console.WriteLine("The location of the sayad id is: " + rect);
                    adadha += text;
                }
            } while (iter.Next(PageIteratorLevel.Word));
        }
    }
}
File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\4020302\\Iron\\f.txt", adadha);

// A method to crop an image using a rectangle
 static Bitmap CropImage(Bitmap source, Rect area)
{
    Bitmap target = new Bitmap(area.Width, area.Height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
    {
        g.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height),
            area.X1, area.Y1, area.Width, area.Height,
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    return target;
}
```

Comment: What did you set as the default language of the tesseract engine?

Comment: I can help but am going to use a commercial library and Google API to translate the Persian text to English and output to the console

Comment: ،Thank you ,I don't have permission to use the Google API in my code due to security issues. Can I do it using C# libraries or python libraries  ?

Comment: Yeah there are millions of commercial libraries that can do what your asking , I see you have coded the location on the cheque with the text as a rectangle. It should be super easy with a commercial library

Comment: Commercial OCR is not like open source OCR libraries. Their text detection mechanism work for most images

Comment: C# commercial libraries will work

Comment: Yeah, There is a C# commercial library called Iron Ocr, they have a one month free trial, download their nuget package, set the language to Persian and you did it

Comment: Provided the sizes of the checks are fixed then we can hand code the rectangle to scan for the Persian text. And then do a console.WriteLine();

Comment: I used Iron Ocr library, but like this library, it did not recognize all Persian numbers

Comment: Which Iron Ocr, did you use a free trial to use the functions of the library?

Comment: If it's open source then that's not the Iron Ocr am talking about.

Comment: This one https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/?

Comment: using System;
using IronOcr;



namespace NumbersExtract
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IronTesseract ocr = new IronTesseract();
            ocr.Language = OcrLanguage.Persian;

            using (OcrInput input = new OcrInput())
            {
                input.AddImage(@"D:\sadad\extract\number.png");

                OcrResult result=ocr.Read(input);

                result.SaveAsTextFile(@"D:\sadad\extract\number.txt");
            }
        }

    }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254977/discussion-between-aidin-barmalaei-and-qing-guo).

Comment: Yeah that's the one